# Using template literals in JSON (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, json, template-literals

I have this JSON object:

`"question": "The question, asked by ${users[index]}, was: \n\n${questions[index]}."`

in a file called "config.json". In a separate file named "app.js", I have this line of code:

`message.channel.send(config.question);`

When the code runs, `message.channel.send(config.question)` outputs:

> The question, asked by ${users[index]}, was:
>
> ${questions[index]}.

Is there any way to treat `${users[index]}` and `${questions[index]}` as template literals? Essentially I want the output to be something like this:

> The question, asked by Steve, was:
>
> Hello world!.

(assuming `users[index] == "Steve"` and `questions[index] == "Hello World!"`)

I searched around for answers, but they all came to using additional Javascript or saying it's not possible. Why, then, if it's not possible, would this work?:

`message.channel.send("The question, asked by ${users[index]}, was: \n\n${questions[index]}");`
outputs:

> The question, asked by Steve, was:
>
> Hello world!.

Comment: No. JSON can only contain quoted strings, not template literals. Where would it get the interpolation values from anyway? You will need to use a proper template engine for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do string interpolation in JavaScript, you need to use backtick (`) for the string literal.

For example:

```
`The answer is ${myVar}!`
```

will interpolate `myVar` into your string.

Comment: Would that go into the JSON `question` object or into `message.channel.send("\`" + config.question + "\`")`?

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
message.channel.send(eval('`'+config.question+'`'))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I searched around for answers, but they all came to using additional Javascript or saying it's not possible

The thing is that those people were not wrong when they told you so. There is not a "native way" to do what you need.

This is an example of the simplest way possible (that crossed my mind) to solve the issue.

```js
//**Your code**
const users=["Steve"];
const questions=["Hello World!"];
const index=0;

//Parse template literals
function parse(expression, object){
    const regexp = /\${\s?([^{}\s]*)\s?}/g;
    let t = expression.replace(regexp, (substring, variables, i) => {
        variables = object[variables];
        return variables;
    });
    return t;
}

//Log the output
console.log(
    parse('The question, asked by ${a}, was: \n\n${b}.', {a: users[index], b: questions[index]})
);


/*CONSOLE OUTPUT: 'The question, asked by Steve, was:
 *
 *                 Hello World!'
 */
```

I hope it's useful!